# Python & Heroku: How to send tasks to background workers in Heroku?

Tags: python, django, heroku, queue, worker

I'm currently building a Django app on Heroku.

I currently have background tasks setup, but I am only able to run tasks on the web dyno instead of the worker dyno.

How can I send tasks to the worker dyno instead? If I run `heroku run python manage.py worker 'queue name'`, it creates a worker within the web dyno, which I'm able to send tasks to via enqueue.

[image]

I have the procfile set to spin up a rqworker in the worker dyno, so that works great.

How exactly can I send tasks (enqueue tasks) into the worker dyno?!

I've followed the tutorials on the heroku site to no avail.

Comment: just giving an option to use gunicorn instead of heroku .... if you want i can help you with the  code

Comment: hey @puneetSinha, thanks for the prompt reply! What do you mean by using gunicorn instead of heroku?

Comment: you want multiple workers or threads to execute your program in parallel right? so gunicorn will do the work for you

Comment: @PuneetSinha that is nonsense. Heroku of a housing service. gunicorn is neither an alternative to Heroku, nr is it capable of running async workers.

Comment: @Jonathan your question is hard to understand. You send tasks to the workers by calling it from within your view, not by spinning up a new worker from the shell.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thanks for the reply Daniel! To elaborate, I have a worker up and running in the worker dyno, I’ve done this by adding worker: python manage.py rqworker queuename inside my procfile. I scale one worker via heroku scale worker=1, and then I run the worker via heroku run worker. I’m trying to find ways to send tasks to the worker, you mentioned to call it from within the views, do you have any recommended tutorials on how to go about this? Thank you!! Will +1 :)

Comment: http://python-rq.org/docs/#enqueueing-jobs

Comment: Hey @DanielRoseman , thanks for the link. I suppose it’s still standard process to run enqueue the job to a worker in another heroku worker dyno the same way it’s done in the link, so long as they both point to the same queue.